# unexpected tINTEGER, expecting $end

Tags: ruby

I'm learning ruby and can't figure out what's the problem here.

```
formatter = "%s %s %s %s"                                                       
puts formatter = % [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Result:

```
ex8.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting $end
puts formatter = % [1, 2, 3, 4] 
                        ^
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with your code?

Comment: It's just an exercise from Learn Ruby the Hard Way.

Comment: I think you want `puts formatter % [1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Comment: And for future reference: [`String#%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-25)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You either **a)** Don't need that `=` sign:

```
formatter = "%s %s %s %s"
puts formatter % [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

or **b)** need to assign the result to `formatter` differently:

```
formatter = "%s %s %s %s"
puts formatter = formatter % [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

or

```
formatter = "%s %s %s %s"
formatter = formatter % [1, 2, 3, 4]
puts formatter
```

The former answer for b will assign the result to `formatter` and then output the result of that assignment, which will be the right-hand side. I'd recommend the latter (and you could of course condense the top two lines into a single line) just because it's clearer.

**Edit:**
Also, if you check [the code in Learn Ruby the Hard Way](http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex8.html), they're not reassigning anything to `formatter`. The point is that you can supply any four-item array via `formatter %` and it will produce the text content of those four items. I see it's just dipping into Ruby methods (and you may be unfamiliar with [printf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string)), but the following are equivalent:

```
puts formatter % [1, 2, 3, 4]
puts formatter.%([1, 2, 3, 4])

# And the very retro
puts sprintf(formatter, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

In other words, while there are a few nuances for operators -- just some sugar that you can actually use things like `%=` to assign the result and you don't need the `.` separating the object and its method -- these are just methods. You can [look up `%` in Ruby's documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-25) like any other method.

Comment: Alright, I see now. The equal sign was giving me syntax errors.

Answer (score 3):

It's not completely clear what is that you are trying to do. Maybe this?

```
formatter = "%s %s %s %s"                                                       
puts formatter % [1, 2, 3, 4]
# >> 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Well these are called format specification with arguments,

```
"I got the following values: %s, %d, %d and %d" % ["Tom", 2, 3, 4]
 => "I got the following values: Tom, 2, 3 and 4"
"%05d" % 123
 => "00123"
```

More you can find at http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-25